# Subtracting float from integer is returning a terminating number

Tags: python

I am trying to build a program that asks for your money and converts it into single dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.

```py
originalvalue = float(input("How much money do you have?\n"))
dollarvalue = int(originalvalue) #This is the amount of single dollars they have
coinvalue = originalvalue - dollarvalue #This is the amount of coins that they have
print(coinvalue, "1")
```

It is returning this:

```
How much money do you have?
5.56
0.5599999999999996 1
```

Shouldn't this be subtracting 5 from 5.56 which should be 0.56.
Is there a way to make this float stop terminating?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.  See also the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the quirks of how decimal values are represented in Python. If you want it to be very exact. Use `decimal.Decimal`

```
from decimal import Decimal

originalvalue = Decimal(input("How much money do you have?\n"))
dollarvalue = int(originalvalue) #This is the amount of single dollars they have
coinvalue = originalvalue - dollarvalue #This is the amount of coins that they have
print(coinvalue, "1")
```

Comment: It's not really a quirk of Python: you would see the same behaviour in most modern programming languages, because binary floating point numbers do not always map exactly to denary floating points numbers.

Comment: It actually does exist on every language because the IEEE standard they are based on are the same. The only issue with python is that it cannot recover the original formatting when printing which most languages can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstain the floating part from rounding as follows.

```
originalvalue = float(input("How much money do you have?\n"))
dollarvalue = int(originalvalue) #This is the amount of single dollars they have
coinvalue = originalvalue - dollarvalue #This is the amount of coins that they have
print(f'{coinvalue:1f}', "1")
```

[Run and test from here.](https://ideone.com/LrC0vW)